# Defining parameters by environment vars that may not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony4

How can parameters be defined so that they are set by environment variables, but they won't cause an error when the environment variable doesn't exist.

In other words, they are parameters not required, but defined by environment variables when they exist.

```
foo: '%env(resolve:MYFOO)%'
```

The example above will generate an error when the environment variable `MYFOO` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value to env vars like this :

```
parameters:
    env(MYFOO): bar
    foo: '%env(resolve:MYFOO)%'
```

If you need to add more specific logic, you can create a `parameters_env.php` file in order to load your environment vars and put some logic in.

For example  :

In **config/config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_env.php }
```

In **config/parameters_env.php**

```
<?php 

if (isset($_ENV['MYFOO'])) {
    $container->setParameter('foo', getenv('MYFOO'));
}else{
    //default value or load from another resource.
}
```